# Other categories in the activity page overlap on "Track the next one"

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, badge-progress, activity

So, I got a discussion tag badge some time ago. When I visited my activity page to check it, I saw something which I think as a bug.

[image: Image showing options overlapping on Track the next one.]

The options in the activity page i.e Summary, questions, answers etc., are covering "Track the next one" button. When we hover on the options, these options take the color of the background.

[image: gif showing change of colors of the options].

This disappears when we click on "Track the next one". It changes to normal.

Comment: I think that the problem is the blue panel with the "track the next one" button: it's too low, so there's a huge, awkward space above it and it ends up behind the other tabs. Under usual circumstances, if the blue box wasn't there, the transparency effect on the tabs wouldn't make a difference.